# Get Error when Permalink Options set "Post name" in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I get error `502 bad gateway` When I set Permalink Options to `Post name`.If I change it to `Plain`, It work successfully.

Why I get this error ?

Comment: you can remove malware from your WordPress website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to web-server , you using nginx web-server and you must follow on google Fix an error 502 bad request nginx .

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2017/07/wordpress-fixing-not-found-error-when-using-pretty-permalinks/) article, this might happen when **mod_rewrite** module is not loaded by Apache.

**UPDATE:**

Maybe the problem is still the same. Check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enabling-nginx-mod_rewrite) page on how to enable Nginx mod_rewrite.

Comment: we use Nginx. not Apache

Answer (score 0):

deactivate your all plugins then try to reset your permalink